# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

Why was my answer deleted @ [How can I fill a screw hole so it can be used again?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21620/how-can-i-fill-a-screw-hole-so-it-can-be-used-again)

My answer was to use a larger screw, and I feel this is a valid and viable answer. I have done it many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was flagged as a possible "*low quality*" answer. It could have been that the answer did not provide enough information, or the answer didn't add any new information.  "*low quality*" flags are a means to prevent "*me too*" type answers, since these types of answers are generally considered to be harmful to the site.

My guess (since I'm not the one who actually closed it, so I can only speculate), is that the closer felt the answer didn't provide enough information.  While "Use a bigger *x*" is my personal motto, it may not be a helpful answer to a novice DIYer.

A more useful answer would provide not only *what* should be done, but also **how** it should be done.  For those of us who know some stuff and are capable, we have to keep in mind that we might be helping folks with little to no experience in this area.  It might feel odd to provide an explanation to such a simple idea, but sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: So, should I re-answer with a better explanation of what I meant, or just leave it?

Comment: If you can still see the deleted answer (which you may not be able to), you can edit that answer. If you can't see it, you are always free to provide another answer.

Comment: A lot of the issues that people have and ask about on the site can often get answered with something simple like use a better screw.  I disagree that this should get deleted.